# Compare two lists and create multiple lists based on matching data

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, match

I have a list of 20 movies, saved like this:

```
library = [
['name1','director1','genre1',running_time_in_mins_1],
['name2','director2','genre2',running_time_in_mins_2],
```

etc up to 20

Based on that library, I need to be able to show the average running time for all movies of a particular genre. I would be looking to output something like: "Average running time for xyz is ### minutes". There could be any number of genres (6 currently in my library) or movies in the library.

I can create a list of unique genres using

```
genre=[]
for y in range (0,len(library)):
    if (library[y][2]) not in genre:
        genre.append(library[y][2])
```

I then thought I would create separate lists for each genre and add the matching run time but this doesn't work

```
for x in range (len(library)):
    for z in range(0,(len(genre))):
        if library[x][2] == genre[z]:
            z=[]
            z.append(library[x][3])
print(z)
```

Comment: Import your list of lists into pandas and use groupby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pandas` is a good library that does what you want, though it’s a little tricky to learn.

For now, try:

```
for genre in set(row[2] for row in library):
    times = [row[3] for row in library if row[2]==genre]
    print("average runtime for", genre, "is", sum(times)/len(times))
```

Answer (score 0):

[List comprehensions](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) are a very useful tool

Getting a list of unique directors:

```
>>> library = [['n1', 'd1', 30], ['n2', 'd2', 40], ['n1', 'd2', 20]]
>>> set([x[1] for x in library])
set(['d2', 'd1'])
```

Getting a list of times for a specific name

```
>>> times = [x[2] for x in library if x[0] == 'n1']
[30, 20]
```

Calculating an average time

```
>>> sum(times) / len(times)  # python 3
25
```

---

But list of list is really not optimal and makes the code unreadable (what's `x[0]`?). Depending on how you get the data, what else you want to do with it and how much time you want to spend learning more python/libraries, I would suggest: list of dictionaries, list of class, pandas dataframe or a database.